# How to transpose multiple txt files?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have 1775 .txt files, and each .txt file has 3023 lines that they looks like this:

```
RIBBY_g_5ZCV995_BI_SNP_D04_38774.CEL
FQC-10090295         0.007813
FQC-10119363         0.023438
FQC-10132112         0.093750
...
```

```
UNTIL_g_3ECO791_BI_SNP_H10_36454.CEL
FQC-10090295 0.187500
FQC-10119363 0.023438
FQC-10132112 0.039063
...
```

How do I make a matrix which represents transposed those txt files so they look like this:

```
                                     FQC-10090295 FQC-10119363 FQC-10132112  ...
RIBBY_g_5ZCV995_BI_SNP_D04_38774.CEL 0.007813     0.023438     0.093750  ...
UNTIL_g_3ECO791_BI_SNP_H10_36454.CEL 0.187500     0.023438     0.039063  ...
```

Comment: how many files are to be processed and what's the approximate size (in lines) of each file?

Comment: there is 1775 .txt files, and each .txt file has 3023 lines

Comment: Whenever you have multiple input files in real life you should provide an example that shows at least 2 input files as with just 1 input file we can't see how multiple affects the output. Get rid of the `...` line from the input, add a second input file (with some different `FQC-...` key values from those in file1 if that's possible in reality) and update the expected output. Right now I don't even know if that'll be 1 output file or 2. Also - is `RIBBY_g_5ZCV995_BI_SNP_D04_38774.CEL` the name of the input file or the first line of the input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem contains many unspecified parameters, but as a starting point, consider this `bash` script:

```
header=

for f in *.CEL
do
    if [ -z "$header" ]
    then
        l=${#f}                 # length of filename ...
        fmt="%-${l}s"           # ... determines width of first column

        header="$(printf "$fmt" "")"    # first column of first row is blank

        for col in $(awk '{print $1}' $f)
        do
            l=${#col}               # width of column
            [ $l -lt 8 ] && l=8     # min width of 8
            header="$header $(printf "%-${l}s" "$col")"     # append column label to header
            fmt="$fmt %-$l.6f"
        done
        printf '%s\n' "$header"         # header is first row of output
    fi

    printf "$fmt\n" "$f" $(awk '{print $2}' $f)     # print filename and all column 2 values
done
```

Running the script gives:

```
                                     FQC-10090295 FQC-10119363 FQC-10132112
RIBBY_g_5ZCV995_BI_SNP_D04_38774.CEL 0.007813     0.023438     0.093750
```

I copied your input file to a second filename, and re-ran:

```
                                     FQC-10090295 FQC-10119363 FQC-10132112
RIBBY_g_5ZCV995_BI_SNP_D04_38774.CEL 0.007813     0.023438     0.093750    
RIBBY_g_5ZCV995_BI_SNP_D04_38775.CEL 0.007813     0.023438     0.093750
```

This script works by first, looping over all `*.CEL` files.

For the first file, the script builds a header line `header` based on the assumption that all the filenames will be the same length.  While
building a header line, the script also builds a `printf` format string `fmt` which will be used for displaying the columnar data.  The first field in the format string is a string of sufficient length to display the filename.

The script next loops over all the "column 1" values in the first input file, which are the value labels.  For each column, the script again takes the length of the value label (but not less than 8), and adds that label to the header.  It also adds a floating-point format spec to the `fmt` string.

After the script has looped over all the column labels, it outputs the header string that has been constructed.

All of the above steps happen for the **first** file only.

The final step in processing the first file, and the **only** step in processing all files after the first one, is to use `printf` to display the filename, and the "column 2" values using the `fmt` string that was created during the first loop iteration.  The script then continues to process the next `*.CEL` file, if any.

This approach assumes that the column labels in all files are the same, and that all the `*.CEL` filenames are the same length.

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you so much! I put your script in transpose.sh and run it like: sh transpose.sh > output.txt Is that how I suppose to run it if not how do I put the output in one file?

Comment: That command will work, so long as you are in the directory where the `*.CEL` files are.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you need:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
FNR==1 {
    row = $1
    rows[row]
    next
}
{
    col = $1
    cols[col]
    vals[row,col] = $2
}
END {
    printf "%s", ""
    for (col in cols) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, col
    }
    print ""
    for (row in rows) {
        printf "%s", row
        for (col in cols) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, vals[row,col]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

but without input/output that clarifies your requirements and we can test against (see [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531926/how-to-transpose-multiple-txt-files#comment984613_531926)), it's just an untested guess.